# How do I black out all screens on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

My company is forcing me to use Windows now (Windows 10 to be specific). Is there a command or something I could run to turn all screens black until I come back to the machine (mouse moves/any key press)?

Also, we always keep a video playing in a loop in Windows Media Player (muted a minimized) keep the screen from locking after 15 minutes.

In Linux I just used "xset dpms force standby".

To people who cannot answer without knowing the reason: I do not want to lock my machine for the night (working from home + mandated super long passwords), but I do not want the screens to shine at night.

Thank you!

PS Maybe I could just open Malevich's immortal painting on all 3 screens somehow?

Comment: Run Nirsoft Monitor OFF.  I use this to turn off my screen on demand. It does not lock the screen or interfere with power management in any way.

Comment: While I was working from home (except for one day per week), I simply pressed the "off" button on the monitors when I left at the end of my one-day-per-week, and pressed the "on" button on the monitors when I came back.

Comment: There is no off button on the laptop's monitor.

Comment: Power options>set Turn off Monitor to 1 minute.

Comment: does not work. We play a video on a loop to prevent the screens from locking in Windows Media Player (muted and minimized, but it tricks Windows into never locking the screen).  That also makes the power options ineffective, it seems.

Comment: You should put that in your question. If you're intentionally running something to keep the screen alive, that's going to actively fight any suggestions people have made so far.

Comment: Wasn't clear from the question that it was a laptop. I figured that you were using the same arrangement I did - a laptop at home that's not so locked down, connecting to and remotely operating your regular desktop system on your desk at the office.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the screensaver to 'Blank' & let it timeout…

[image]

Comment: Not an option since the company IT locks down many system settings. :(

Comment: This won't keep the machine dark while he's working from home.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - You don't need the screen dark whilst you're working ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - If I'm working from home, I don't need whoever's in the office "looking over my shoulder".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - I'm really not exactly sure what point you're trying to make. OP wants screens to go black whilst not using them, without password lock triggering. Until it was added that there's an intentional keep-awake running, this would have just been a simple set & forget.